# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date exception

Tags: java

If I do `toString` on  a `Date` object, I am getting the output as below

```
2016-04-13 22:00:01.0
```

I am doing the below to convert the object to Data again

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:SS");
Date convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(timestamp.toString());
```

But getting the `ParseException`.

I am trying to get the output as Date object as below
2016-04-13 22:00:01

Comment: The cast to `Date` is unnecessary because `formatter.parse(...)` already returns a `Date` object.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.

Comment: If i remove the casting also still i am getting the parsing error please help

Answer (score 4):

This test should cover your example:

First from comment:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date convertedDate = formatter.parse("Thu Apr 14 15:24:14 CEST 2016")
    System.out.print(convertedDate);
```

Second from question:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date convertedDate = formatter.parse("2016-04-13 22:00:01.0");
    System.out.print(convertedDate);
```

It all depends on input String that you are receiving.

You should not use Date::toString method, use formatter, as you willl have no problem with zones and formats. It's better to have full flow control over your data.

Now if you want to convert it to a " 2016-04-13 22:00:01" format, simply use:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formatedDate = formatter.format(convertedDate);
```

Comment: The above didnt work. Date is retruned as Thu Apr 14 00:39:57 IST 2016

Comment: This code   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  Date convertedDate = formatter.parse("2016-04-13 22:00:01.0");                                                                                              returns only the below format                                                                  Wed Apr 13 22:00:01 IST 2016. But my desire output is different
  System.out.print(convertedDate);

Comment: @magesh-balasubramaniam done. But I would advise to use same formatter to convert to and from String. So that you would not have to use more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Parse from String with a certain date-format to a Date object:

```
    String dateString = "2016-04-13 22:00:01.0";
SimpleDateFormat formatterFullMilliseconds = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" );

Date dateFromDateString = formatterFullMilliseconds.parse( dateString );

System.out.println( dateFromDateString ); // Output: Wed Apr 13 22:00:01 CEST 2016
```

Parse a java.util.Date object to the string representation you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
System.out.println( formatter.format( dateFromDateString ) ); // 2016-04-13 22:00:01
System.out.println( formatter.format( new Date() ) ); // 2016-04-14 15:29:04
```

Comment: I have a date Object if i do datObject.toString() i am getting the output i need, but the function that ia m trying to pass the value accepts only Date object. Hence your solution might not work for me

Answer (score -1):

```
yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:SS
```

should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

Comment: Thanks that resolved the exception issue, but i need ouput only in the format 2016-04-13 22:00:01 not 2016-04-13 22:00:01.9

Comment: Sorry it didnt work.Date is retruned as Thu Apr 14 00:39:57 IST 2016

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what you need to do, to escape java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date exception

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date dt = sp.parse(sp.format(date));
System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

Comment: if I put 2014-10-30 18:10:50, i get 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date